# How to recognize selected text in image

Tags: java, android, tesseract

I am using tesseract library of google to convert an image to text. My problem is how to recognise text if I tap and select a part of the image text.

Comment: check this api to get text from an Image http://ocrapiservice.com/documentation/app/android/

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the "OCR Test" app in the play store. The code is available in the description of the app. It implements a Viewfinder that enables you to select a part of a image to apply the OCR.